# Função não definida com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Fiz um cshtml e nele há um botão que chama minha função que insere no BD. Acontece que quando eu clico no botão, me dá esse erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: InsereCadastro is not defined. O que eu preciso fazer para contornar esse erro? Achei que não fosse necessário mais nada, pois o botão chama a função. Veja meu código:
Meu cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Cadastro</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Util.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form role="form" class="">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="txtNmCadastro" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Nome completo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-2" id="txtNmCadastro" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="txtEmail" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control col-lg-2" id="txtEmail" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail válido">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="txtEndereco" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Endereço</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-2" id="txtEndereco" name="Endereco" placeholder="Digite seu endereço">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="txtBairro" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Bairro</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-2" id="txtBairro" name="Bairro" placeholder="Digite o bairro">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="txtCidade" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Cidade</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control col-lg-2" id="txtCidade" name="Cidade" placeholder="Digite a cidade">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="txtTelefone" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Telefone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-2" id="txtTelefone" name="Telefone" placeholder="Digite o número do seu telefone">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <label for="txtCelular" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Celular</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-2" id="txtCelular" name="Celular" placeholder="Digite o número do seu celular">
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="btnGravarCadastro" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Gravar" onclick=" return InsereCadastro();" />
        </div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Meu arquivo .js(jquery)

```
function InsereCadastro() {

    var resultado = jQuery.parseJSON('{ "nmcadastro": "' +$("#txtNmCadastro").val() + '" , "email_cadastro": "' + $("#txtEmail").val() + '" , "end_cadastro": "' + $("#txtEndereco").val() 
                                        + '" , "bairro_cadastro": "' + $("#txtBairro").val() + '" , "cidade_cadastro": "' + $("#txtCidade").val() + '" , "uf_cadastro": "'+ $("#cbxUf").val() 
                                        + '" , "tel_cadastro": "' + $("#txtTelefone").val() + '" , "cel_cadastro": "' + $("#txtCelular").val() +'" }');

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Cadastro/InsereCadastro',
        datatype: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ _cadastro: resultado }),
        success: function (data) {

            alert('Registro gravado com sucesso.');

        },
        error: function (error) {

            alert('Erro ao tentar gravar o registro.');
        }

    });
}
```

O código de minha controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public void InsereCadastro(tbl_cadastro _cadastro)
        {

           using (INETGLOBALEntities db = new INETGLOBALEntities())
           {
               tbl_cadastro tb = new tbl_cadastro();

               try
               {
                   tb.nmcadastro = _cadastro.nmcadastro;
                   tb.email_cadastro = _cadastro.email_cadastro;
                   tb.end_cadastro = _cadastro.end_cadastro;
                   tb.bairro_cadastro = _cadastro.bairro_cadastro;
                   tb.cidade_cadastro = _cadastro.cidade_cadastro;
                   tb.uf_cadastro = _cadastro.uf_cadastro;
                   tb.tel_cadastro = _cadastro.tel_cadastro;
                   tb.cel_cadastro = _cadastro.cel_cadastro;

                   db.tbl_cadastro.Add(tb);
                   db.SaveChanges();
               }
               catch (Exception ex) 
               {
                   Erro = "Erro na gravação do registro: " + ex.Message;
               }

           }
```

Comment: qual é o nome do arquivo onde está a função `InsereCadastro`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe duas possibilidades

- A função realmente não foi declarada, você esqueceu de chamar o seu arquivo javascript
- Existe algum erro no seu arquivo javascript antes de vocẽ declarar a função

Você colocou esta função no seu arquivo Util.js?